# Rails routing to subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

We have a site at www.example.com but needs to move it to subdomain1.example.com, while maintaining the SEO links. We are planning to use Google's Change of Address but it requires 301 redirects.

We plan to release another site at the www.example.com address.

Is there a way to changes the `routes.rb` of www.example.com so that certain routes gets redirected to `subdomain1` and others don't?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by redirect but here are some options:
You can redirect a route to another route in your rails app using:

```
get '/some_route', to: redirect('/other_route')
```

Or if the subdomain is a seperate app / service you can redirect in a controller using:

```
redirect_to "http://www.rubyonrails.org"
```